# problem making file automatically readable to another user?

Tags: linux

User want from now all files it creates automatically readable to user sparrow, but for no other user. How can he ensure that this happens, the next time he logs in?

Comment: Is "sparrow" the user who will create the files or a different user?

Comment: no it is another user

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. If you feel the question is on-topic, then see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might also try [how do linux file permissions work](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+linux+file+permissions+work).

Answer (score 0):

I assume the user who created the file should be able to read it as well. I will call him "creator". I further assume that the files should be owned by "creator".

The solution depends on your distribution. If every user has its own group, e.g. group "sparrow" for user "sparrow" only, you can use this group "sparrow" instead of "coworker". If all users share a common group, e.g. "users", you could create a new group that is assigned to user "sparrow" and optionally also to user "creator" as a secondary group. I call this group "coworker".

To make sure that new files get assigned this group "coworker" you can `chgrp coworker somedirectory` and `chmod g+s somedirectory` for every directory where "creator" might create files for "sparrow".
You might have to use `umask` as well to make sure the newly created files are readable for the group. You also must make sure the directory permissions grant user "sparrow" read and execute access (or at least execute access).

Answer (score -1):

### If the user creating the files *is* sparrow:

Edit their shell config (`.bash_profile` or whatever is appropriate for their shell) and add a [umask](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html) command:

```
umask 077
```

This disables read/write/execute permissions for group/other, for all new files and directories created. (Note this doesn't prevent those permissions from being changed later, it just sets the initial values.)

### If the user creating the files is *not* sparrow:

There is no way to automatically do what you desire. I think the closest you can come is to create a new group, make that group the default for both users, and then set this user's umask to 007.

Comment: I think this contradicts the requirement "readable to user sparrow, but for no other user"

Comment: Hmm, well I've assumed that the user doing the file creation *is* sparrow, perhaps not. I'll clarify.

Comment: I thought that "sparrow"` is a different user from the user who creates the file. My previous comment applies to this assumption.

Comment: Heh yeah, just figured that out. :)

Comment: This will work for files created from the command line and any app that inherits the user's environment. (I.e., certain apps might set specific permissions.)